# Building an HTML flask web page - input dependent on launch

Tags: python, flask

I am building a website with flask on python. I am new to web development.

I built an HTML page, and now I need it's contents - **number** of buttons on the page for example - to be possibly different and automatic on each launch of app.py (the flask app running the website). Let's say that the number will be random between 1-10, a number generated in the app.py.

Does this mean that I need to change the HTML on every app.py launch, this by **using python and editing the *text file* "index.html"**? Is this bad practice and not a good way of achieving the goal? Are there other better methods to launch an input-dependent HTML page?

Thanks!

Code example:

```
def change_HTML_page(path,num):

    # here read the text file in path, which is an HTML file, page description. 
    # inside in some place add more rows to describe buttons,
    # as many as num.
    # Add rows like this one <input type="button" id="i_bnutton" value="i" onclick="change_button_appearence(this)" />
    # save text file afer the change
        

  
num_of_buttons = randint(0, 10)
page_path = r"docs/pages/index.html"

change_HTML_page(page_path, num_of_buttons);


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to pass the num_of_buttons inside the html render command and constract all input buttons with a jinja loop inside your html.

Your code should look like below:

FLASK:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    num_of_buttons = randint(0, 10)
    return render_template('index.html', num_of_buttons=num_of_buttons)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

And inside your HTML:

```
{% for i in range(0,num_of_buttons) %}

<input type="button" id="{{i}}_bnutton" value="{{i}}" onclick="change_button_appearence(this)" />

{% endfor %}
```